# how to terminate a timer thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

i have a code to run a timer thread and its doing a job every x seconds and its has no problem

```
import threading
import datetime

def starThread():
    t = threading.Timer(0, Do_Analysis())
    t.start()

def Do_Analysis(): 
    #define  threading.Timer to do the job every x secound
    t=threading.Timer(1, Do_Analysis).start()
    print('datetime is : ',datetime.datetime.now())
    print(threading.active_count)

starThread()
```

i need to **terminate** the thread at some point and i dont know how to do it
can anyone please guide me

Comment: You can cancel a waiting timer via the [`threading.Timer.cancel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer.cancel) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
t=threading.Timer(1, Do_Analysis)
t.start()
if True:
    t.cancel()
```